# How do I strip <link> tag from javascript String object using Regex or some better alternative?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is code:

```
   <div class="rightColoumn" id="divreports">
       <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
       <link href="../ClientScript/General.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </div>
```

I wish I could remove  lines completely.

javascript String object **strObject** contains this html.

Comment: use HTML/Javascript to remove `link` nodes from DOM.

Comment: `/<link\b[^>]*?>/gi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove all `<link>` tag?

```
   var reg= /<link\b[^>]*?>/gi
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RPDeT4-csP3s6Q2n)

Comment: Thanks, it's the most handy solution

Comment: how could I modify regex to remove all <script> tags as well?

Comment: @BubbaYakoza `var reg= /<\/?script\b[^>]*?>/gi`

Comment: @BubbaYakoza - It seems like you're getting very close to [**TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) now.

Comment: @Tim.Tang Thanks, it removes the script tags but does not remove the code in between. any help?

Comment: @BubbaYakoza ok, try this `var reg= /<script\b[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi`

Answer (score 2):

How about just parsing it as what it is, HTML

```
var strObject = '<div class="rightColoumn" id="divreports"><link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"><link href="../ClientScript/General.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></div>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc    = parser.parseFromString(strObject, "text/html");
var parent = doc.getElementById('divreports');
var links  = parent.getElementsByTagName('link');

for (var i=links.length; i--;) parent.removeChild(links[i]);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/92e388f1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to remove < link tag lines:

```
strObject.replace(/^.*<link.*$/mg, "");
```

It will work if your string has line break '\n' at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Here  try this way to remove html tag

```
    //link
      var reg= /<link\b[^>]*?>/gi



    return this

        .replace(reg, '$1<link href="http://$2">$2>')

};
```